# Is it possible to have application.properties depend on multiple profiles?

Tags: spring-boot, profile

Is it possible to have a Spring Boot properties file depend on two or more profiles? Something like `application-profile1-profile2.properties`?

Comment: No. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: Not sure about properties file , but yaml files can be configured that way. More details here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml

Comment: But keep in mind of issue with yml: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ways I know.

1. insert `.yaml` or `.properties` programmatically like Asi Bross Said. Use `ResourceLoader` or [YamlPropertySourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-exposing-yaml-to-spring) to insert.
2. Use `.yaml`. but it will be replace when you have a another spring project to dependent it.
3. Use properties instead of profiles. (For api project)

   1. Use one `@PropertySource` to define properties file A.
   2. Get the variables from properties file A and assign them to the parameters in another `@PropertySource` file path expression.

   For example:

   ```
   resources
   /-application.properties  <-- remove or empty,because it will be override by application project
   /-moduleA
        /-application.properties               <-- Intellij can identify properties files started with application-
        /-application-mysql-dev.properties
        /-application-psql-dev.properties
        /-application-psql-prod.properties
   ```

   The content of `resources/moduleA/application.properties` :

   ```
   moduleA.custom.profile1=mysql
   moduleA.custom.profile2=dev
   ```

   Content of Java Config file:

   ```java
   @SpringBootApplication
   @PropertySources({
           @PropertySource("/moduleA/application.properties"),
           @PropertySource("/moduleA/application-${moduleA.custom.profile1}-${moduleA.custom.profile2}.properties"),
   })
   public class ModuleConfig {}
   ```
4. Use properties instead of profiles. (For application project)

   ```
   resources
   /-application.properties
   /-application-mysql-dev.properties
   /-application-psql-dev.properties
   /-application-psql-prod.properties
   ```

   The content of `resources/application.properties` :

   ```
   moduleA.custom.profile1=mysql
   moduleA.custom.profile2=dev
   ```

   The content of `SpringMvcApplication.java`:

   ```java
   @SpringBootApplication
   @PropertySource("/application-${moduleA.custom.profile1}-${moduleA.custom.profile2}.properties")
   public class SpringMvcApplication {...}
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot does not support this out of the box. It only supports a single profile as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).

However, it does provide enough flexibility to add your own property sources using EnvironmentPostProcessor.

Here is an example of how to implement this:

```
public class MultiProfileEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor, Ordered {
    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();

        for (int i = 2; i <= activeProfiles.length; i++) {
            Generator.combination(activeProfiles).simple(i)
                    .forEach(profileCombination -> {
                        String propertySourceName = String.join("-", profileCombination);
                        String location = "classpath:/application-" + propertySourceName + ".properties";

                        if (resourceLoader.getResource(location).exists()) {
                            try {
                                environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource(propertySourceName, location));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("could not add property source '" + propertySourceName + "'", e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Couple of things to note:

- This implementation only supports `.properties` files but can easily be extended to `.yml` files as well.
- getActiveProfiles already returns the profiles in an order where the last one wins. This implementation relies on this order and builds the different file names leveraging this order. i.e. if active profiles are: profile1,profile2,profile3 then `application-profile1-profile3.properties` is supported but `application-profile3-profile1.properties` isn't, and `application-profile1-profile3.properties` will override properties defined in `application-profile1.properties` or `application-profile3.properties`.
- This implementation uses a third party library `com.github.dpaukov:combinatoricslib3` to create the different sets of profiles.
- The property sources are added to the front of the property source list to override existing sources. But if you have custom property sources that should take precedence you need to modify this a bit to consider them in the order, i.e. by leveraging methods like `Environment.addAfter`.
- Registering an EnvironmentPostProcessor is done using the `spring.factories` file.